# Use python to modify bone and mesh pose

Tags: python, rigging, bones

I have downloaded [this rigged avatar](https://free3d.com/3d-model/rigged-male-human-442626.html). I also have a list of 3d positions corresponding to different body parts (left/right foot, hands, knees, elbows, head, ...).

What is the best way to set the avatar's body parts to the same locations?

I tried this:
`bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].bones['forearm.L'].tail = (1,2,3)`

but it does not update anything.

I also tried this in Edit mode:

```
bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].edit_bones['forearm.L'].tail = (1,2,3)
```

However, this only changes bone position and not attached mesh. It also mirrors changes to forearm.R.